# How to know the status of a SSL socket in Boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

In normal connections, asuming a socket:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket  socket_;
```

it's possible ask the socket status with:

```
if (socket_.is_open()) { ... }
```

But instead, in secure connections, asuming a socket:

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
```

There is not an `is_open()` method for the `socket_` object, so the question:

Is there a similar way to know the socket status?

Comment: you should accept some answers to your previous questions, doing so will likely generate more and better answers for future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
if ( socket_.lowest_layer().is_open() ) {
    // do something great
}
```

see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/lowest_layer.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your input. Although usually I try do my work with the Doc before posting some question, this time I was unable to find that.

Comment: @Old no problem, the way Asio has wrapped SSL support is somewhat confusing at times.